# How to use count number of rows which meet the condition in ssrs report?

Tags: reporting-services, report

In my report I want to count number of rows with condition. For example Count Mondays, count weekdays, count Saturdays, etc.

[image]

I try with this :

```
=countdistinct(iif(weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)=1,Fields!N_ENTERED.Value,0))
```

but give me the result `18`. I expected `1`, because I have only 1 monday between `09.06.2019` and `16.06.2019`

The entered value is entered calls from employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `countdistinct` is returning the number of unique values you have in your `N_ENTERED` field, not the number of Mondays.

To just count the number of Mondays, you need to reference the result of your `iif` instead:

```
=sum(iif(weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)=1, 1, 0))
```